# Notation in harmonic series

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, notation, harmonic-numbers

I was looking at an answer of the post [Awfully sophisticated proofs for simple facts](https://mathoverflow.net/a/44742), where the topic was the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} $, and I found this notation:
$$ f_n := \frac{1}{n} 1_{[0,n]}$$

What does that $1$ with that subindex mean?
And, when should I use that notation?

Comment: $1_{[0,n]}$ is a function and at a point $x$, it outputs $1$ if and only if $0 \le x \le n$, and $0$ otherwise. You should use it whenever you want.

Comment: Thank you! Is that notation very standard? Is there maybe a Wikipedia article? A link to other math sites or articles would be helpful too.

Comment: no problem; yes; yes; look up "indicator function"

Comment: Oh, I had heard about the characteristic function before, but I never use it so I guess that's why I did not recognize it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Comment: @mathworker21 , I think that pretty much solved the problem. Would you mind writing an answer so I can accept it?